# Is there an unofficial term for an artifact that produces mana?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, terminology

Some terms have an unofficial but widely known meaning in Magic jargon. For example, a "cantrip" is a spell that lets you draw a card, and a "bear" is a vanilla 2/2 (with "vanilla" having its own meaning!)

What about a card that produces mana like [Sol Ring](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Sol%20Ring), [Rakdos Signet](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rakdos%20Signet), or [Talisman of Indulgence](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Talisman%20of%20Indulgence)? Do they have an unofficial name?

Answer (score 11):

The canonical name for these seems to be 'Mana Rocks', probably so named after one of the very first, [Fellwar Stone](http://gatherer.wizards.com/pages/card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=247152).

Comment: The number of Google results is impressive. This does indeed appear to be an accepted term.

Comment: Does a Mox count as a "Mana Rock"?  How about a Black Lotus?  Surely not!

Comment: I'm pretty sure the name refers to the Moxes, not Fellwar Stone.

Comment: I'm less sure it refers to the Moxes (though not entirely sure it refers to Fellwar Stone either); the term seems to have primarily originated in EDH/Commander play, where moxen are outright banned.  It's more likely than anything else, I suppose, to be an offshoot of 'brown' as the color of artifacts and the notion of artifacts as generically being mineral of some sort or another.

Comment: "Mox" is typically a term to itself meaning a 0-cost artifact that produces mana.

Answer (score 2):

"Mana Rocks" might be a genuine term, but I don't think it's a particularly useful one, as it's not very descriptive of the *use* of these cards.

If I was talking about this class of card, in a way more likely to explain why I'd want to include some in my decks, I'd just go for "artifact-based mana acceleration".  I know this answers your question less well than Steven's answer, but on the other hand I, and I'm sure many others, would never use the term "mana rocks"!